# Why is the work done by the parallel component of gravity equal to $mgh$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, work

I understand the mathematics behind why they are equal but I don't understand it in terms of intuition , for example when moving a cart along an incline plane the work done by the parallel component of fg is equal  to mgh why is this , isn't the parallel displacement different from the vertical displacement(h).

Comment: How much work does gravity do when the box moves over a horizon surface?

Comment: Yes it is different, as you said. The only thing that matters for gravity is the height h, not how far you have moved horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Gravity does no work when the cart moves horizontally over the ground. Work is only done when the force is parallel to the motion. Because only then does it have an influence.

A motion along an incline corresponds to a motion horizontally and a motion vertically at the same time. Gravity has no influence on the horizontal part, which is why it makes no difference of you move horizontally (has a horizontal component) or not - only the vertical motion is influenced. And if you move just as far vertically in both situations, then gravity does the same work in both situations, regardless of any simultaneous horizontal motion.

Comment: If gravity has no influence on the  horizontal part , then how is it than an object can fall down an incline ,by just raising the angle of the incline

Comment: @LM26 Because a normal force appears and causes the sideways push.

Comment: Your answer does not make sense , the normal force acts in a perpendicular direction to the sideways push , hence it will not cause a sideways push

Comment: @LM26 A normal force is exactly perpendicular to **the surface** that causes it (thus the name normal). A normal force from an inclined surface is therefore tilted - it has a horizontal component. So gravity gives the falling object it's vertical component of acceleration, and this normal force gives it it's horizontal (sideways) component. Combined, they cause a motion along the incline.

Answer (score 0):

If you push a cart up a slope of angle $\theta$ for a distance $s$ then the work done by the external force is $mg\sin \theta \,s$ where $mg \sin \theta$ is the component of weight of the cart down the slope.

However the vertical height through which the cart is raised is $h = s \sin \theta$.

So the work done in pushing the cart up the slope is $mg\sin \theta \,s = mgh$